# react axios can`t get data from expressjs

Tags: reactjs, express, proxy, cors, apache2

everyone! 
I use Apache2 as proxy for reactjs

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8082/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8082/
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain
    ErrorLog /var/www/mydomain/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/mydomain/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

in react/package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=8082 react-scripts start",
},
```

BACKEND:
in group.routes.js:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-client-key, x-client-token, x-client-secret, Authorization");
    next();
});
```

in server.js:

```
let allowlist = [
 'http://localhost:8082', 
 'http://localhost:8083',
];
```

```
var corsOptionsDelegate = function (req, callback) {
  console.log('req: ',req)
  var corsOptions;
  if (allowlist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
    corsOptions = { origin: true } // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response

  } else {
    corsOptions = { origin: false } // disable CORS for this request
  }
  callback(null, corsOptions) // callback expects two parameters: error and options
}
app.use(cors(corsOptionsDelegate));
```

Please, help me, why I get this error? In localhost it is working like charm 
 (indeed, in local machine
there is not configured domain name, just launching through http://localhost:8082 ).

But when I run it in remote machine by mydomain.com expressjs does not response with expected json data.

The error shown in dev tools of browsers is below:

Firefox:
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4002/api/group/getAllGroups. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).`

Chrome:
`GET http://localhost:4002/api/group/getAllGroups net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Axios:
`code: "ERR_NETWORK"`
`message: "Network Error"`
`name: "AxiosError"`